# Xtensa Xplorer - Failed to Install Configuration Build

Tags: embedded, signal-processing, firmware, xtensa

am trying to run for the first time a "Hello world" program on Xtensa Xplorer , but when am trying to install configuration build , it gives me this error saying "Non-interactive mode"
[Failed to install configuration build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh5UX.png)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for us is unpacking configuration tarball and running install.exe that can be found inside (run it in cmd). That gave us more comprehensive error message.
For us it was that MSVCR120.dll was missing in path (that dll is even included in the tarball itself). Just copied it next to the install.exe and rerun it and installation completed successfully.